# How do I import modules with JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to React. I have added it to a project using the information on this site:

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

```
Run npm init -y (if it fails, here’s a fix)

Run npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3
```

Then,

```
npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod
```

Whenever I try adding a module it gives me:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

Here is how I am importing :

```
import { PostcodeLookup } from "@ideal-postcodes/postcode-lookup"
```

(I've tried this at the top of my react js file and in a seperate script file called in a componentDidMount() method via:

```
 const script = document.createElement("script");

script.src = "my_script.js";
script.async = true;

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the `import React from 'react'` statement, and how is that js file connected to your html?  If you are linking the file containing this code from a `<script>` tag in your HTML, you need to give that script tag a `type="module"` attribute.

Comment: I changed the question a bit because I didn't want people to assume it was an issue with the specific import and not just importing as a whole and the structure of my project.

I've attempted putting the import at the top of the js file with the react components and then I tried in a script file that is appended in a componentDidMount() method but neither worked.

Am I importing in the wrong place?

Comment: I'm super confused as to why you are defining your script tag with `createElement`, instead of just writing it into your html header.  Even so, you still didn't set `script.type = "module"`.  And Where is this code even being run?  In some *other* js file that is linked in the actual HTML?  We need clarification to undertand how your project is set up.

Comment: Gosh I am an idiot this has been bugging me for hours and I didn't realise the answer was so simple.

Putting the import in a script, adding script.type = "module", and adding the script to the header of the html file worked perfectly, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Notice how in the page you linked there's no reference to `import`s or `export`s.
Also how that page says:

> Tip
> We’re using npm here only to install the JSX preprocessor;

This means it will only process JSX expressions into `React.createElement` function calls. If you want to use modules, you will either need to use native modules by changing the `type` of your `<script` to `module`

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js">
```

or use a bundler.

To use a bundler, check out the next page of the React tutorials:
https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Answer (score 0):

The steps you mentioned are for jsx setup. Can you paste complete error message ?
Have you installed React in your existing project ?

You perhaps have to install React to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

With export class Arrow... you have to use import {Arrow}... whereas with export default class Arrow... you have to use import Arrow.... In the former case, there might be multiple export... statements in a file and therefore your import statement has to be able to handle importing multiple variables by placing that potential list of variables in braces. With export default... there can be only a single export from that file and therefore the import statement can confidently assert that it is importing a single variable, i.e. import myVariabl